# Inserting distinct values from XML into table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, service-broker

I have a table with a complex primary key. Also I have a Service Broker service which receives XML message which basically looks like the following:

```
  <TableName>
    <CHANGED key1="1" key2="2" key3="3" timestamp="00:00:01"/>
    <CHANGED key1="1" key2="2" key3="3" timestamp="00:00:02"/>
    <CHANGED key1="1" key2="2" key3="3" timestamp="00:00:03"/>
  </TableName>
```

My goal is to insert those values into a table.

I tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, TS)
  SELECT 
      Tbl.Col.value('@*[1]', 'int'),
      Tbl.Col.value('@*[2]', 'int'),
      Tbl.Col.value('@*[3]', 'int'),
      Tbl.Col.value('@*[4]', 'datetime')
  FROM   @MESSAGE.nodes('//CHANGED') Tbl(Col)
```

But in case when we have several records with the same complex key (key1, key2, key3) and different timestamp (value I need for my biz logic) this query fails with the following error message:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'TableName'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.TableName'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1, 2, 3).

Is there a way to insert only distinct values with the latest timestamp from that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `group by` on the keys and aggregate on `timestamp` (min or max?).

```
INSERT INTO TableName (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, TS)
SELECT key1, key2, key3, MIN(ts)
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      Tbl.Col.value('@key1', 'int') AS key1,
      Tbl.Col.value('@key2', 'int') AS key2,
      Tbl.Col.value('@key3', 'int') AS key3,
      Tbl.Col.value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as ts
    FROM   @MESSAGE.nodes('//CHANGED') Tbl(Col)
  ) AS M
GROUP BY key1, key2, key3
```

To be really safe you should use the attribute names instead of `position()`. According to [Limitations of the xml Data Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28SQL.90%29.aspx?ppud=4) the order of attributes is not guaranteed.

> The order of attributes in an XML instance is not preserved. When you
>   query the XML instance stored in the xml type column, the order of
>   attributes in the resulting XML may be different from the original XML
>   instance.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!!! And thank you about your comment about attributes, I'll take this into account.